# Set Mail From Name via Virtual Host for sendmail

Tags: virtualhost, sendmail

I have an issue with a Magento 2 store not setting the **from path** and **from name** for some reason.

After a few hours of debugging I have decided to work around it temporarily while i figure out the main issue. I have however multiple site instance and need to set the **sendmail** values per store in their vhosts.

So far i have set the **from path** correctly with the below in my `httpd.conf`:

```
php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -fsales@domain.co.uk -t -i"
```

What is the equivalent for the **from name** e.g Website Sales?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (from the Postfix variant of `sendmail`):

```
-F full_name
   Set the sender full name. This overrides the NAME environment variable, 
   and is used only with messages that have no From: message header.
```

which should be used like

```
-F 'Sales Department <sales@example.com>'
```

resulting in

```
php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -fsales@domain.co.uk  -F 'Sales Department <sales@example.com>' -t -i"
```

Comment: So like below: php_admin_value full_name "/usr/sbin/sendmail -fSales Department -t -i"

Comment: No, according to your question, you want to shoehorn it into the sendmail call, so it's another parameter to your command. See my edit.

Comment: Sorry not really my thing servers ha. Thanks so much for your help however that worked perfectly.